# PayPal IPN Help (Not UPDATE Database)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi there all been trying to get this working for about 2 days now. The Payment is going through no problem but it not update the Database :(

Here is the Code :

```
<?php

require_once(WWW_DIR."/lib/users.php");


            // Connect to database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Test
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Live
// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$name = $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$contact_phone = $_POST['contact_phone'];
$email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$uid = $users->currentUserId();
//timezone set
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
} else
{
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)  {
if($payment_status != "Completed"){
                if($payment_amount == 2.00)
                {
                    $role = 6;
                }
                else
                if($payment_amount == 5.00)
                {
                    $role = 8;
                }
                else
                if($payment_amount == 8.00)
                {
                    $role = 9;
                }

                //update user records
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE users SET role = %d WHERE ID = %d", $role, $uid);
mysql_query($sql);  


 //log payment
            //mysql_query("INSERT INTO payments (email, item_name, payment_status, txn_id, payment_ammount) VALUES('" . mysql_escape_string($email) . "', '" . $item_name . "', '" . $payment_status . "', '" . $txn_id . "', '" . $payment_amount . "' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
      }} else
            if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0)
            {
                // log for manual investigation
            }
    }
    fclose($fp);
} 
?>
```

If you have any Questions just ask I will try and Answer ASAP if you could get this working I would be very happy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

To:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Change:

```
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)  {
```

To:

```
if (strcmp(trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0)  {
```

And lastly, change:

```
if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0)
```

To:

```
if (strcmp(trim($res), "INVALID") == 0)
```

Reason:
The PayPal Sandbox is configured to reject HTTP 1.0 requests without a Host header specified, so your current script will never properly validate.